# Thread in Windows form application won't work

Tags: c#

Hey guys I am new here and i just started learning programming in c#. Can any of you please help me with this problem of mine here... I want to make a simple program where on (button 1) i start a countdown and i want to be able to abort it on (button 2). I am using threads.

When i try to run (debug) the program it says : 
(Error 1 A field initializer cannot reference the non-static field, method, or property 'okey.Form1.CountDown()')

i want to learn how to use threads in windows forms application.
Thanks in advance!

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Speech.Synthesis;
using System.Threading;


namespace okey
{

public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    Thread countdown = new Thread(new ThreadStart(CountDown));

    private static SpeechSynthesizer synth = new SpeechSynthesizer();
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        countdown.Start();
    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        countdown.Abort();
    }

    public void CountDown()
    {
        synth.Speak("Starting!");

        for (int i = 10; i >= 0; i--)
        {
            richTextBox1.AppendText(i + "\r\n");
            System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Delay(1000).Wait();
            richTextBox1.Clear();

        }
      }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
namespace okey
{
  public partial class Form1 : Form
  {
     Thread countdown;
     private SpeechSynthesizer synth = new SpeechSynthesizer();
     public Form1()
     {
       InitializeComponent();
       countdown = new Thread(new ThreadStart(CountDown));
     }        

     public void CountDown()
     {
      synth.Speak("Starting!");
      for (int i = 10; i >= 0; i--)
      {
        richTextBox1.AppendText(i + "\r\n");
        System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Delay(1000).Wait();
        richTextBox1.Clear();
      }
     }
   } 
}
```

Comment: public void CountDown() changed to public static void CountDown() -Now when I try to run (debug) the program it says: Error 1 An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'okey.Form1.richTextBox1'